# User data recovery, Bitlocker not letting OS boot.

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partition, data-recovery, bitlocker

A user on our network recently could not boot into
their Windows 7 Enterprise laptop.

We have the BitLocker Key, and even after entering it
The installation will not get past the Windows logo.

It will not boot into safe mode either.

Attempting to use a recovery CD/USB, gets as far as
Unlocking with our key, and then hangs, and crashes.

After putting the drive into a Dock, we can use the 
key to unlock the Bitlocker, and then scan, but we
can only see the manufacturer tools partition, and the
recovery partition. The installed partition is missing
on Scans, although can be seen from explorer, although
not opened.

Is there a tool, way to recover from this situation?

There is no damage to the disk, it wasn't dropped and 
the other partitions look and act normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, there may be a hardware problem. If the data it critical contact a data recovery company. Depending where you are some good ones can be found here ..

http://globaldra.org

You could first try mounting the drive on another windows computer to see if that will access. But if it hangs again, seriously consider data recovery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A few other laptops bought at the same time started showing the same symptoms. I was able to rescue data from 2 drives using dislocker from live USB, but on the third one, the drive failed before I could get to it. Looks like the 3 hard drives were indeed failing.